# First commenters are not automatically notified of responses from the OP on Teams

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, comment-replies

It's standard behavior on the sites that the OP can respond to the only person who has commented on their post *without* using an @reply... this is helpful, **particularly for new users who may not realize that the site has a reply function** at all.

For some reason, however, this functionality is disabled on Teams. This means that the behavior we've been trained to follow causes a lack of notification in some cases. I've had this happen to me from both sides and I'd prefer that the behavior be fixed to match the way the full site automatic comment replies work. We already automatically notify the OP of the post of comments but this caveat seems to have been missed.

Comment: Pings on teams behave very differently: you have to choose a specific user for the ping, and the published comment contains a link to the pinged user. I presume this very different behaviour is to blame (i.e. the whole machinery is probably new).

Comment: If we wanted to make this behavior a bit more discoverable, automatically inserting the @-name when the comment is posted (or... even after the author starts typing) would suffice.

Comment: Do you mean specifically on Teams @Shog9 ? Or everywhere? Right now I occasionally get pings from posts that I've commented on that aren't directed at me because they're the OP commenting on their own question about something unrelated to my comment... such as downvotes or adding more info instead of editing the question.

Comment: specifically on Teams, @Catija. I tend to think it'd just be noise everywhere else, unless we end up porting the behavior of Teams to normal-site comments, in which case we'd probably want to re-think how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should now work on Teams the same way it works on public sites, with one difference: we'll insert the @username of the other commenter into the post owner's comment.

Here's an example:

> 1. This is a comment on your question -- SomeCommenter
> 2. Why, thank you! -- QuestionOwner

The second comment would become:

> 1. This is a comment on your question -- SomeCommenter
> 2. @SomeCommenter Why, thank you! -- QuestionOwner

This was done mostly for ease of implementation - the new mentioning system in Teams assumes non-post-owner mentions are explicit and visible in comments.